# BASH: how can I save the exit code in PS1 in order to use it later in PS1?

Tags: prompt, bashrc, exit-status

I am attempting to customize my PS1, in the following way (I have removed the colours):

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w$(git_branch)$(useExitCode)\$ '
```

where

```
git_branch()
{
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
```

As for exit status, I would like to pick it up **before** the `git_branch` function is executed, and use it in `useExitCode` . How can I do that? The latter function could look like this:

```
useExitCode()
{
    local exitCode=${1}

    if [[ ${exitCode} == 0 ]]; then
        echo ':)'
    else
        echo ':('
    fi
}
```

The question is, how can I store the exitcode in PS1 and use it later ?

Something like the following does not work, but gives an idea of the geenral direction:

```
PS1='exitCode=$?\u@\h:\w$(git_branch)$(useExitCode ${exitCode})\$ '
```

The above echo's the "exitCode=0" (or =1) part but it is not stored, so it is empty at its invocation "${exitCode}" later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable for that:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='lstatus=$?'
PS1='$(false)$(exit 3)<$lstatus> '

<0> sh -c 'exit 17'
<17> echo $?
17
<0>
```

From the `bash(1)` manpage:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>              If set, the value is executed as a command **prior** to issuing each
>              primary prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar with my prompt, and here is how I go a "get the `git` branch in my prompt while still showing the last command's exit code" thing:

```
 parse_git_branch() {
     exit_code=$?
     local stdcolor
     local branchcolor
     local lines
     stdcolor="^[[0;32m"
     if [[ -d ./.git ]] || $( git status > /dev/null 2>&1 ); then
        lines=$(git status -s | wc -l)
        if [[ 0 -eq ${lines} ]]; then
           # Working copy is clean
           branchcolor="^[[1;32m"
        elif git status -s 2> /dev/null | grep -q '^A'; then
           # If we have staged commits waiting, red; else yellow
           branchcolor="^[[1;31m"
        else
           branchcolor="^[[1;33m"
        fi
        git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/ $stdcolor($branchcolor\1$stdcolor)/"
     fi
     return $exit_code
  }
  export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\e[38;5;14m\]\u\[\e[38;5;8m\]@\[\e[38;5;6m\]\h\[\e[38;5;8m\]:\[\e[38;5;10m\]\w'"\$(parse_git_branch) \e[31m\${?##0}\n"'\[\e[$(((($?>0))*31))m\]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

The (sanitized) resultant prompt and how it looks while in a `git` workspace:

```
me@host:~/src/project (devel)
$ false
me@host:~/src/project (devel)  1
$ true
me@host:~/src/project (devel) 
$
```

The upshot of all that is that:

- If I am in a `git` workspace, my current branch is shown.  Green if clean, yellow if dirty, and red if there are staged files waiting for a commit
- If the last command's exit code was nonzero, it is shown (in red) in the prompt, and I still have access to `$?`.